# What is this kind of linear map called?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, extension-field

Say we two fields $K \subset L$, and an automorphism $\sigma : L \to L$ fixing $K$.  I have an $L$-vector space $V$, and a map $t : V \to V$ with $t(lv) = \sigma(l) \, t(v)$ for $l \in L$ and $v \in V$.

It's a $K$-linear map, but not $L$-linear.  Is there a name for such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your $t$ preserves sums too, it is a [$\sigma$-semilinear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilinear_transformation).

(In the particular case that $L=\mathbb C$ and $\sigma$ is complex conjugation it is "conjugate linear" or "antilinear").

Comment: Who knew!  Thanks! (will accept as soon as it lets me)